# Cannot insert special symbols to Oracle database

Tags: c++, database, oracle, soci

I tried to add special symbols (i.e : æ_ø_å_Æ_Ø_Å_____£€$&@%¿) to Oracle database table VARCHAR2 column and different results noticed in following methods.

**Database character set :** `SELECT * FROM nls_database_parameters WHERE parameter LIKE '%SET';
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_CHARACTERSET    WE8MSWIN1252`

**SQL used :**

```
INSERT INTO Test(C1) VALUES('æ_ø_å_Æ_Ø_Å_____£€$&@%¿');
```

1. ***Insert Directly via SQL Developer***

**Result :** `æ_ø_å_Æ_Ø_Å_____£€$&@%¿`

2. ***Insert via SQLPlus***

**Result :** `¿¿_¿¿_¿¿_¿¿_¿¿_¿¿_____¿¿¿¿¿$&@%¿¿`

3. ***Insert via C++ code using SOCI library***

**Result :** 
While using database connection string (WINDOWS_1252 charset) : `"oracle://service=<service> user=<user> password=<password> charset=178 ncharset=1000";` result was
`Ã¦_Ã¸_Ã¥_Ã†_Ã˜_Ã…_____Â£â‚¬$&@%Â¿`

While using database connection string (UTF_8 charset) : `"oracle://service=<service> user=<user> password=<password> charset=871ncharset=1000";` result was
`æ_ø_å_Æ_Ø_Å_____£€$&@%¿`
 C++ code used :

```
std::string dbConnectionString = "oracle://service=<service> user=<user> password=<password> charset=178 ncharset=1000";
soci::session dbCon;
dbCon.open(dbConnectionString.c_str());
soci::statement *cursor = nullptr;
std::string selectString ="INSERT INTO Test(C1) VALUES('æ_ø_å_Æ_Ø_Å_____£€$&@%¿')";

try
{
    cursor = new soci::statement(dbCon);
    cursor ->alloc();
    cursor ->prepare(selectString);
    cursor ->define_and_bind();
    cursor ->execute(true);
}
catch (soci::soci_error const & e)
{
    std::cout <<"ERROR :  ." << e.get_error_category() << " : "<<e.what()<<  std::endl;
}
```

What is the reason for this inconsistent behavior?

Comment: The reason is the different clients. SQL*Plus is CLI and do not support the special symbols

Comment: Thanks @Tejash. what about the 3rd case?

Comment: 3rd case is related to C++ and I am not aware about it